# PagerAdapter() cannot be applied to android.app FragmentManager

Tags: android

I tried to create a ViewPager in Android Studio.
I get the error:

```
PagerAdapter() cannot be applied to android.app FragmentManager
```

at the line `super(fm);`

Here is my code for the adapter. Do I need to change anything?

```
package com.example.admin.usthweather;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 11/15/2017.
 */

public class HomeFragmentAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
  private final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
  private String titles[] = new String[] {"Hanoi","Paris", "Saigon"};

  public HomeFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
  }

  // Override
  public Fragment getItem(int page) {
// returns an instance of Fragment corresponding to the specified page
    Fragment frag=null;
    switch (page){
      case 0:
        frag=new Hanoi();
        break;
      case 1:
        frag=new Paris();
        break;
      case 2:
        frag=new Saigon();
        break;
    }
    return frag;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fm` in `super(fm);` is wrong. Therefore none of this is necessary:

```
public HomeFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
}
```

However, I suspect that you did not want to subclass [PagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html), but either   or [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html). As the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) say:

> Base class providing the adapter to populate pages inside of a ViewPager. You will most likely want to use a more specific implementation of this, such as FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter.
>
> Instead of providing a View recycling mechanism directly ViewPager uses callbacks to indicate the steps taken during an update.

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor in [PagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) with FragmentManager as parameter. You're code is similar for [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) or [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) so you can use one of them. It will be something like this:

```
public class HomeFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

  private final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
  private String titles[] = new String[] {"Hanoi","Paris", "Saigon"};

  public HomeFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int page) {
    Fragment frag=null;
    switch (page){
      case 0:
        frag=new Hanoi();
        break;
      case 1:
        frag=new Paris();
        break;
      case 2:
        frag=new Saigon();
        break;
    }
    return frag;
  }
}
```

Please remember to use the correct import file for `Fragment` and `FragmentManager` from Support library:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```